# Whats better, make a loop reading php in android or make a loop in php reading a database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, server

i am making an application in android that has to read constantly a database hosted in my server, my question is, is better make a loop in android, reading the php document constantly or just read once but the php document makes a loop to get information from a database?

in android studio i just make a loop with a sleep, and read the php document. I don't have the code because i haven't made it, but here is the code to connect with php, just imagine it in a loop:

```
    StringRequest conexion = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constantes.URL_NombreIcono,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if(response.charAt(response.length() - 1) == '1'){

                    }
                    else {
                        NombreGrupo.setText(response);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast("No se ha podido conectarse con la base de datos", "l");
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requ.add(conexion);
```

and the php code in this case is like this:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'JNDatabase');
if (!$con) {
    echo "|Error";
}
else{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Log ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $resultado = $con->query($query);

    if (!$resultado){
        echo "|Error";
    }
    else {
        $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
        if($row["Realizada"] == 1){
            echo $row["Accion"]."|".$row["id"];
        }                                       
    } 
}
```

?>

The other case, is read the php document once, but the php document makes the loop, i have the code of the loop in php:

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

while (true) {
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'JNDatabase');
    if (!$con) {
        echo "|Error";
    }
    else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Log ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $resultado = $con->query($query);

        if (!$resultado){
            echo "|Error";
        }
        else {
            $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
            if($row["Realizada"] == 1){
                echo $row["Accion"]."|".$row["id"];
            }                                       
        } 
    }
    ob_flush();flush();sleep(1);
}
```

?>

so which do you think is better,having in mind that is an android application  and i have to take care about the battery.

PDT: I know that exists services like Firebase, but i want to do this with my own server, you know, try to avoid giving the information to other companies

Comment: as a rule of thumb always do the work the closest to the DB you can.

Answer (score 0):

In Android it depends what will you do with data received from your database. But definitely you shouldn't make loop in PHP. What it will do when Android device is off-line? PHP should get data from database (maybe from cache) and pass it to Android device by request.

If you want to show data from database in UI and nothing else, you can use any loop or Handler.postDelayed() API. But would be nice if you will pause your work when application closed or paused.

Or if you want do some work in background like storing data in SQLite you can use AlarmManager or JobScheduler API. [There is a list of available tools](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html).